# Fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory in compiling C program using GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Why when I wan to compile the following multi thread merge sorting C program, I receive this error:

```
ap@sharifvm:~/forTHE04a$ gcc -g -Wall -o mer mer.c -lpthread
mer.c:4:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
ap@sharifvm:~/forTHE04a$ gcc -g -Wall -o mer mer.c -lpthread
mer.c:4:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define N 2  /* # of thread */

int a[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};  /* target array */

/* structure for array index
 * used to keep low/high end of sub arrays
 */
typedef struct Arr {
    int low;
    int high;
} ArrayIndex;

void merge(int low, int high)
{
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        int left = low;
        int right = mid+1;

        int b[high-low+1];
        int i, cur = 0;

        while(left <= mid && right <= high) {
                if (a[left] > a[right])
                        b[cur++] = a[right++];
                else
                        b[cur++] = a[right++];
        }

        while(left <= mid) b[cur++] = a[left++];
        while(right <= high) b[cur++] = a[left++];
        for (i = 0; i < (high-low+1) ; i++) a[low+i] = b[i];
}

void * mergesort(void *a)
{
        ArrayIndex *pa = (ArrayIndex *)a;
        int mid = (pa->low + pa->high)/2;

        ArrayIndex aIndex[N];
        pthread_t thread[N];

        aIndex[0].low = pa->low;
        aIndex[0].high = mid;

        aIndex[1].low = mid+1;
        aIndex[1].high = pa->high;

        if (pa->low >= pa->high) return 0;

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++) pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, mergesort, &aIndex[i]);
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++) pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

        merge(pa->low, pa->high);

        //pthread_exit(NULL);
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
        ArrayIndex ai;
        ai.low = 0;
        ai.high = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])-1;
        pthread_t thread;

        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, mergesort, &ai);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf ("%d ", a[i]);
        cout << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<iostream>` and `using namespace std;` are for C++, not for C.

Comment: This looks like a C++ program not a C one. Better save it as some `.cc`  file and compile it with `g++`, not `gcc` ; or change it to a C99 program.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Neither `<iostream>` nor `<iostream.h>` are standard C header files. Your code is meant to be C++, where `<iostream>` is a valid header. Use a C++ compiler such as `clang++` or `g++` (and a `.cpp` file extension) for C++ code.

Alternatively, this program uses mostly constructs that are available in C anyway. It's easy enough to convert the entire program to compile using a C compiler. Simply remove `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`, and replace `cout << endl;` with `putchar('\n');`... I advise compiling using C99, C11 or C18 (eg. `gcc -std=c99`, `clang -std=c18` etc)

Answer (score 9):

Seems like you posted a new question after you realized that you were dealing with a simpler problem related to `size_t`. I am glad that you did.

Anyways, You have a `.c` source file, and most of the code looks as per C standards, except that `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`

C equivalent for the built-in functions of C++ standard `#include<iostream>` can be availed through `#include<stdio.h>`

1. Replace `#include <iostream>` with `#include <stdio.h>`, delete `using namespace std;`
2. With `#include <iostream>` taken off, you would need a C standard alternative for `cout << endl;`, which can be done by `printf("\n");` or `putchar('\n');`
   Out of the two options, `printf("\n");` works the faster as I observed.

   When used `printf("\n");` in the code above in place of `cout<<endl;`

   ```
   $ time ./thread.exe
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

   real    0m0.031s
   user    0m0.030s
   sys     0m0.030s
   ```

   When used `putchar('\n');`  in the code above in place of `cout<<endl;`

   ```
   $ time ./thread.exe
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

   real    0m0.047s
   user    0m0.030s
   sys     0m0.030s
   ```

Compiled with Cygwin `gcc (GCC) 4.8.3` version. results averaged over 10 samples. *(Took me 15 mins)*

Comment: Where's your code? Which compiler, standard library and commands are you using to compile the code?

Comment: Really? You print _one_ character, time it and despite the margin of error caused by heaven forbid task switching, one is really considered faster than the other? That is your testing methodology? Wow, just wow!

Comment: If you were to compile to assembly (e.g. using `gcc -O3 -S your_printf_file.c`) you might notice that your `printf` call gets translated to a `putchar` call... There is an old saying which I'm sure google can finish off for you, it starts along these lines: Premature optimisation is...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: FWIK, TBH, I didn't know that it gets translated to `putchar`, and always thought (and still believe) that it gets translated to `write` call. Verified that with `strace` utility. And it doesn't do what you are referring to.

Comment: That's not what happens on my system, but then again I'm using gcc 4.5.2. I suppose, along-side task switching being a more significant margin of error than the optimisation itself, this is just another factor indicating that "Premature optimisation is ...".

Comment: ...the root of all evil. So, I'll leave that to OP to decide what to use. But, glad that you suggested me to compile to assembly, which I have never tried seriously.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error : -

```
fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
```

After some time I found that, I'm making a very very noob mistake here. Actually  I was running my program file by giving the extension `".c"` only.... :-(
So check whether you're saving your file with proper extension or not...
In this case, it'll be .cpp for C++ program file. So check that once and maybe you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

So now first check if you have downloaded the MinGW and have added it to the env variables

to check use `g++ --version` on your cmd/terminal

now if the squiggly lines still appear install the `c++ Intellisense` extension
you will mostly get an error in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file because the compiler path may not be correct

so all you have to do is put the correct path and the swiggly lines will dissappear