# iostream not found in .cc file

Tags: c++

I am compiling a .cc file, which now uses

```
extern "C"
```

before main(),
included files are relevant project headers as well as

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

now i have to use std::vector in main, therefore i add

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
```

and delete stdio.h,
stdlib.h was changed to cstdlib.

but g++ reports

```
fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory 
#include<iostream>
compilation terminated.
```

how can i use .cc file and program with C style as well as c++ containers?

thanks a lot

Comment: Could you share an [mcve]?

Comment: Did you check that you have the iostream header file?

Comment: it's in a project where main function is not exactly called as int main(), therefore hard to give a minimal reproducible example. in /usr/include/c++ there are many versions, in folder "8" there is an "iostream" header

Comment: What about this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30543316/6941952)?

Comment: Do you call gcc or g++?

Comment: g++ is used. I looked for the difference between .cc and .cpp, but these two indicates no differences.

Comment: Why are you doing `extern "C"`? Just use `<cstdio>` and `<cstdlib>` if you need stuff from there.

Comment: A [mcve] doesn't have to be your actual code, just something that is enough to describe what your doing and if it also replicates the error then the better. Anyway, we need to see more of what you do, more context. And if possible also show the exact command line used to build, copy-pasted as text.

Comment: Your compiler installation seems broken and there's not enough information to suggest a fix.